# How to deploy MVC 2 application on Mono hosting ? how to check if MVC is supported?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mono

I have a very simple MVC2 apllication and it works when I start it in Visual Studio (on the dev. webserver)

I try to deploy this on a mono hosting, but currently no luck.

## 1 I'm not sure about the following about the applicaion:

how to deploy MANUALLY a mvc2 application - no matter if on mono or on windows asp.net.
I don't know which files I need to copy where.

## 2 I'm not sure about the mono hosting:

when I put a simple aspx page to get version info I get the followin:

> 2.6.7 (tarball Tue Aug 31 04:50:05 MSD 2010)
> according the mono 2.6.7 release notes mvc2 is supported...

when I try to run the MVC2 app after copying the files on the host server via filemanager I get the following instead of index:

> Index of /
>
> - Parent Directory
> - Global.asax
> - Web.config
>
> Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2
> mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 mod_mono/2.6.3 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1
> mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 SVN/1.6.17 mod_perl/2.0.5
> Perl/v5.8.8 Server at ..........

Any hints on manual deploying of MVC2 and on mono MVC2 support will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance
Best Regards
Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **1**

In **MonoDevelop**, there is an option called **"Deploy to Web..."** in the **"Project"** menu item that will help you export only the files you need to run your site (I believe there is a similar option in **Visual Studio** called **"Publish to Web"**). Keep in mind that you need to set the build action to **Content** for any non-code files you want included in the export, i.e. picture files, style sheets, etc.

### **2**

Running MVC2 sites using Mono isn't as straightforward as simply installing the runtime. You'll need a capable web server. In most cases, that web server will be Apache with the **mod_mono** mod enabled. I've only been able to get it to work using **mod-mono-server4**, which requires the Mono 2.8 runtime. You'll also need a specific Virtual Host configuration.

A nice walkthrough for getting all of the above working can be found here: [How to get ASP.NET MVC 2 working with Mono in 10 Steps](http://buddylindsey.com/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-2-working-with-mono-in-10-steps/)